# Why are interacting noncommutative quantum field theories with space-time noncommutativity unitary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity, non-commutative-theory

Can anyone explain in a simple manner why interacting noncommutative quantum field theories with space-time noncommutativity of the Moyal bracket sort are unitary?

Comment: This is a bit over my head (and same goes for most people here), but I do hope you get a good answer. (If nobody else contributes then perhaps I'll see if I can research it a bit, if/when I get time)

Comment: This paper seems relevant http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0005129